# change column value in multiple column to NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this df dataset

this is some of columns in my dataset

```
GarageType       GarageFinish    GarageQual       PavedDrive       WoodDeckSF
Attchd           RFn             TA               <NOT AVAILABLE>  0
Attchd           Unf             TA               P                298
Detchd           Unf             <NOT AVAILABLE>  P                300
BuiltIn         <NOT AVAILABLE>  FA               P                80
<NOT AVAILABLE> <NOT AVAILABLE>  FA               <NOT AVAILABLE>  150
```

I want only column start with "Garage" and change value NOT AVAILABLE to NA

Be like this

```
 GarageType       GarageFinish    GarageQual       PavedDrive       WoodDeckSF
 Attchd           RFn             TA               NA               0
 Attchd           Unf             TA               P                298
 Detchd           Unf             NA               P                300
 BuiltIn          NA              FA               P                80
 NA               NA              FA               NA               150
```

I know how to change all of the NOT AVAILABLE to NA in dataframe with this code

```
df[df=="<NOT AVAILABLE>"]<-NA
```

But i want it like this, to change NOT AVAILABLE to NA in column with name "Garage"

```
df %>%
   select(starts_with("Garage"))%>%
   .....
   is.na() %>%
   colSums()
```

i dont know how to fill it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `na_if` function does that for you:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~GarageType, ~GarageFinish,
    "Attchd", "Rfn",
    "Attchd", "Unf",
    "Detchd", "Unf",
    "BuiltIn", "<NOT AVAILABLE>",
    "<NOT AVAILABLE>", "<NOT AVAILABLE>"
)
df %>%
    select(starts_with("Garage"))%>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("Garage"), ~na_if(., "<NOT AVAILABLE>")))
```

Comment: The OP said that they only wanted columns that started with "Garage," and `select` does that; I guess the mutate command could be `mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., "<NOT AVAILABLE>")))`, though since only columns that start with "Garage" would be included in `df`

Comment: well in that case you are right. upvoted already